# If statement in underscore to check a condition?

Tags: html, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I want to check if this array (member.team_member_designations) being passed through the template is an array or a string. If it's an array, I want it to move forward with the HTML below it, otherwise, if it's a string, to just print the string. How do I write this in the underscore template? Right now, I'm just checking for an array but want to include a check for string and the condition to print it if its a string.

HTML:

```
<%- _.isArray(member.team_member_designations)  %>
<% _.each(buildDesignationDictionary, function(designation) { %>
<p> <%- designation.title %> </p>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Wait wait, why are you using ERB tags?

Comment: I'm using underscore in my HTML template, so used those tags to render underscore code

Comment: To render underscore code? Those tags are used to insert eRuby code.

Comment: @Bálint http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 2):

use `<% code %>` to evaluate javascript.

```
<% if( _.isArray(member.team_member_designations)){  %>
    <% _.each(buildDesignationDictionary, function(designation) { %>
        <p> <%- designation.title %> </p>
    <% }) %>
<%}else if( _.isString(member.team_member_designations) ){ %>
    <%- member.team_member_designations %>
<% } %>
```